# In UEC, created volume appears, disappears, why?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-computing, cloud-storage, disk-volume, uec

I've installed UEC and got it up and running but when I create a volume and attach it to an instance it appears and disappears. and in my instance I can't seem to see it using sudo fdisk -l

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running 10.10 ? coz that contains eucalyptus-2 which may have resolved that bug. Make sure all components are up2date. Are you still seeing that behaviour? Any errors on the CC host ?